# Why is my C:\ a shared folder?

Tags: networking, hard-drive

I'm wondering if I got hacked. I noticed my C:\ was shared, wtf. Maybe it has to do with how MacFUSE connects to my Windows partition in Mac OS X.

Comment: What's it shared as?  It's not the default `C$` share, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Larry Osterman from Microsoft answers this question here:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150806202917/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/05/26/422188.aspx)

> Out-of-the box, a Windows system automatically shares the root of
> every hard drive on the machine as $ (so you get C$, D$, A$,
> etc).
>
> ...
>
> the development lead for Lan Manager (Russ (Ralph) Ryan) needed to
> change a config file on the LanMan server that hosted the source code
> for the Lan Manager product.  And he realized that none of the file
> shares on the machine allowed access to the root directory of the
> server!  He couldn't add a new share remotely, because the UI for
> adding file shares required that you navigate through a tree view of
> the disk - and since the root wasn't shared, he could only add shares
> that lived under the directories that were already shared.
>
> ...
>
> Nowadays, with RDP and other more enhanced remote administration
> tools, it's less critical, but there are a boatload of products that
> rely on the feature.

Comment: Wait, so if Microsoft simply produced a command line share-editing tool, this wouldn't be a problem? I don't have any lemons for sale, would you to try our hammers for $4.99 a piece?

Comment: If Microsoft had produced a command line share-editing tool, that tool would need some way to create shares, like for example admin shares.

Comment: @AndrewJBrehm, I don't understand why the root drives would have to be shared by default in order to use/add them later. Why not have the share editor allow you to specify a plain Windows path on your local computer (or the one you're connecting to remotely)?

Comment: I assume that without the root shares it would be difficult to verify if you had permission to share whatever path you enter.

Comment: Whoever has permission to modify the share settings would have sufficient rights to the partitions on the machine.

Comment: Hence the admin shares. Without them, that statement wouldn't be true.

Answer (score 5):

By default C:\ is shared as a "hidden", admin-only share called C$.  Only admins can access the share and the permissions cannot be changed.  If it was shared as some other name, it would indicate either you, another admin or program running as admin added the share.

To minimize the possibility of the latter happening in the future, do not login regularly as an admin (assuming you do so now - if not, congrats!).